# page being redirected on form submission but not on button click using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have been trying to implement page redirection functionality in my Spring-MVC application using AJAX. The page is successful being redirected on form submission when I am using html form. But I do not want to use form and instead I want to execute AJAX request on button click. But the page is not being redirected when I am using AJAX call and this warning is being displayed on Eclipse console: `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'`. So my question is that if the page is successfully being redirected with form submit button then why it is not being redirected with AJAX code? And what should I do to redirect the page on button click using AJAX code?

**index.jsp *(Using FORM, which is working)***

```
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Spring Page Redirection</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Spring Page Redirection</h2>
      <p>Click below button to redirect the result to new page</p>
      <form:form method = "GET" action = "/HelloWeb/redirect">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input type = "submit" value = "Redirect Page"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>  
      </form:form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp *(Using AJAX, which is not working)***

```
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Spring Page Redirection</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Spring Page Redirection</h2>
      <p>Click below button to redirect the result to new page</p>
      <button onClick="redFun()">Redirect Page</button>
      <script>
            function redFun() {
                type : "GET",
                url : "/HelloWeb/redirect"
            }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**final.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Spring Page Redirection</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>Redirected Page</h2>
   </body>

</html>
```

**WebController.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class WebController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index() {
       return "index";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String redirect() {

      return "redirect:finalPage";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/finalPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String finalPage() {

      return "final";
   }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: have you tried using the full url instead of relative path?

Comment: yes. but getting same error